# how to use wait with watir-webdriver

Tags: watir-webdriver

I am trying to implement wait for page to load in watir-webdriver but none of these work for me:

http://watirwebdriver.com/waiting/

I am trying to wait for following element

```
<a>
  <img width="22" height="32" align="absmiddle" title="Sign out" alt="Sign out" src="images/logout.gif">
  Sign out
</a>
```

Few questions:

1. Do I need to include some library and then use the wait methods
2. in RubyMine, all methods mentioned on above link are not displayed for the element above? is there any setting that I nee to make?
3. Does watir-webdriver work or preferred for gwt based web apps?

Please help.
Umar

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You say "none of these work for me" but you didn't include samples of the code you tried and what errors or other problems resulted.

Assuming your browser object is @browser, I'd suggest trying one of these and letting us know the result(s):

```
@browser.link(text: "Sign out").wait_until_present # try this
@browser.img(title: "Sign out").wait_until_present # ...or this
```